# With jfeinstein10's slidingmenu,how to use button to bring out right menu

Tags: android, menu, slidingmenu

With jfeinstein10's slidingmenu,how to use button to bring out right menu(I want two method to summon the right and left menu.And I use the onclickevent with toggle to bring out the left menu.But I don't know how to bring out the right menu with a button).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption that *right menu* means the secondary menu that is available with that library, you can use:

`SlidingMenu.showSecondaryMenu(boolean animate)`

You also have `SlidingMenu.showMenu(boolean animate`, if it's the other menu that you want to show.

For reference, you can see the source code of this [library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java).

Edit: 
Since a lot has happened since the question and answer was posted a link to NavigationDrawer might be in order: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: The link is outdated, FYI.

Comment: Link updated and added a link to NavigationDrawer since that is an official component.